# Not able to display 2 JTable's horizontally in swing

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I need to display 2 `JTable`'s along x-axis. I am able to display them vertically (Y-axis.) This is what so far I have done:

[image: Displaying Two tables.]

But I want to display tables like the following,

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    tableA = new JTable(data, colNames);
    tableB = new JTable(data, colNames);

    JLabel labelA = new JLabel("Table-A");
    JLabel labelB = new JLabel("Table-B");

    JButton bt_copy = new JButton("Copy");

    Container c = frame.getContentPane();

    c.setLayout(new BoxLayout(c, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    c.add(labelA);
    c.add(tableA.getTableHeader());
    c.add(tableA);

    c.add(labelB);
    c.add(tableB.getTableHeader());
    c.add(tableB);

    c.add(bt_copy);
```

When I changed Y-axis in **`c.setLayout(new BoxLayout(c, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));`** to **X-axis**. I really got a bad GUI view.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11912364/1048330) @MadProgrammer positioned two tables using `GridBagLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ??

[image: Layout]

```
JTable leftTable = new JTable();
JTable rightTable = new JTable();

addButton = new JButton("Add >>");
removeButton = new JButton("<< Remove");

setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

// Prepare the buttons panel...
JPanel pnlActions = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
pnlActions.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 1;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
gbc.weighty = 1;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
pnlActions.add(addButton, gbc);
gbc.weighty = 0;
gbc.gridy++;
pnlActions.add(removeButton, gbc);

// Prepare the main layout
gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.weightx = 0.33;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc.weighty = 1;

add(new JScrollPane(leftTable), gbc);
gbc.gridx = 2;
add(new JScrollPane(rightTable), gbc);

gbc.gridx = 1;
gbc.gridy++;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.weighty = 0;
add(pnlActions, gbc);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a `GridBagLayout` instead of `BoxLayout`. And instead of adding everything to a `JFrame` itself, try adding a `JPanel` to the frame and adding your tables to the frame. (*This would mean that you would set the layout of the panel to `GridBagLayout`*).

If you are new to Layout Managers, try to read the [Visual Guide To Layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#box). It is pretty informative.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Box for the contentPane.  You'll need to use a combination of boxes to get the desired layout you want.  Here's an example that should get you close:

```
tableA = new JTable(data, colNames);
tableB = new JTable(data, colNames);

JLabel labelA = new JLabel("Table-A");
JLabel labelB = new JLabel("Table-B");

JButton bt_copy = new JButton("Copy");

Box v = Box.createVerticalBox();
frame.setContentPane(v);

Box c = Box.createHorizontalBox();
v.add(c);

JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(tableA);
c.add(jsp);

jsp = new JScrollPane(tableB);
c.add(jsp);

Box c2 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
c2.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
c2.add(bt_copy);
c2.createHorizontalGlue();

v.add(c2);
```