# Swing / AWT implementation of "PickList"

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I'm looking for a component which provides functionality similar to this: [image: a "PickList"]

After googling around, this seems to be called a "PickList". Please correct me if I'm wrong.

So far I found implentations in various languages, but not for Java. Actually, I found **three** implementations of a "PickList" in Java, but all of them are made for JSF, not Swing or AWT.

You can find a simple demonstration of the needed functionality [here](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=pickList).

Any pointers to a library implementing this would be appreciated.

PS: Of course I could build this component myself. But I'd prefer to use existing code...

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912100/how-to-add-two-columns-in-a-jlist/11912364#11912364

Comment: take a look here: <http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/DualListBoxSample.htm>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such component in [JideSoft](http://www.jidesoft.com) library (you can quickly find it in demo app by keyword "DualList"), but it is a commercial library. I don't know any open-source analogues.

Anyways, it shouldn't take much time to create this component by yourself - few buttons, two lists and a bit of work with data. You can even implement DnD pretty quick there.